# Slicing a data frame and adding valued based on different slice

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame with a column representing phases ('A', 'B', and 'C'). I need to slice the data frame so I have only column 'A', divide it by 2 and add the value to the other column.

Here is an example:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {'time': [1,2,1,2,1,2,],
        'phase': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C' ],
        'value': [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

   time phase  value
0     1     A      2
1     2     A      3
2     1     B      4
3     2     B      5
4     1     C      6
5     2     C      7


slice_A = df.loc[df['phase']== 'A', 'value'] /2 
print(slice_A)

0    1.0
1    1.5
Name: value, dtype: float64

df.loc[df['phase']=='B', 'value'] += slice_A

df
time    phase   value
0   1   A   2.0
1   2   A   3.0
2   1   B   NaN
3   2   B   NaN
4   1   C   6.0
5   2   C   7.0
```

I understand this is because the index of `slice_A` is not the same as:

```
df.loc[df['phase']=='B', 'value']
```

I tried to reset the series with the index of the sliced data frame. I also tried to work with data frames instead of series, but I couldn't get it to work. But, I am still getting Nan values.

Comment: Hi, do you mind writing the expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert your series into numpy array to avoid index alignment:

```
df.loc[df['phase']=='B', 'value'] += slice_A.to_numpy()
print(df)

# Output
   time phase  value
0     1     A    2.0
1     2     A    3.0
2     1     B    5.0
3     2     B    6.5
4     1     C    6.0
5     2     C    7.0
```

Obviously it works because your have as many A as B. You can add to B:

- a scalar value like `3`
- an array of one element `[3]`
- an array of the same shape (here `(2,)`)
- a series with the same index

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to apply this to all rows (not just "B" rows), then you could use the following, which also works for any given number of rows of "A", e.g. 3 of each group:

```py
df.value.add(df.groupby("phase").cumcount()
             .map(df[df.phase.eq("A")].value.div(2).reset_index(drop=True)))\
    .sub(df.phase.eq("A").div(2))

#Out[]: 
#0    2.5
#1    4.0
#2    5.0
#3    6.5
#4    7.0
#5    8.5
#dtype: float64
```

This calculates the cumulative count and maps this with the halved "A" values.  Then subtracts the addition from "A" again.